# Bootstrap NavBar questions

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a NavBar that looks like this (what I want). But I have a couple of questions around it.

[image]

The NavMenu.razor is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">BlazingTopMenu</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler @NavButtonCssClass" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse"
                aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse @NavBarCssClass" id="navbarCollapse" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <span class="navbar-text">
            Election in 5 days
        </span>
    </div>
</nav>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private string? NavBarCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? null : "show";
    private string? NavButtonCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapsed" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

[Which I got from martinmogusu.](https://github.com/martinmogusu/blazor-top-navbar)

A couple of questions:

1. If the web page gets any narrower than shown, the menu collapses to the hamburger icon. Why does it collapse when there is so much room left?
2. Is there a way, when it gets narrower, to have the menu stay up, but become just the icons with a tooltip of the icons being the text?

And to confirm I understand this markup:

1. <nav nav-bar-expand-md> says to expand/collapse the nav bar as needed. If that is removed is there a way to force the navbar always up (I removed it and it was then always hamburger)?
2. The whole <button> part in there is the hamburger button tied to the appropriate pieces of the navbar content.
3. Is the <lt;button> shown/hidden based on class="navbar-toggler" and the data-bs- and aria- settings?
4. Is the navbar items shown/hidden by <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">?
5. How does the navbar items know if they should display horizontally or vertically?
6. The various mb-2, mb-4, mb-md-0 is all to adjust margins. Is this standard practice? Or are there bootstrap theme settings one should use so that everything stays consistent. And that a theme change adjusts everything?
7. The display/hide of the menu is controlled by the

Answer (score 0):

You included both the bootstrap-4 and bootstrap-5 tags, but since you’re using Bootstrap 5 (data-bs-toggle="collapse" is for BS5, not 4), I’ll address your points based on BS-5.

**As to your two questions:**

1. If the web page gets any narrower than shown, the menu collapses to the hamburger icon. Why does it collapse when there is so much room left?

*The collapse point is controlled by the breakpoint specified by the `navbar-expand` class (e.g. `navbar-expand-md`). Bootstrap doesn’t adjust the collapse size based on your content.*

2. Is there a way, when it gets narrower, to have the menu stay up, but become just the icons with a tooltip of the icons being the text?
   To have the menu always shown, use the class `navbar-expand` class with no breakpoint. To show just the icons on small screens, enclose the text in a span tag and use Bootstrap’s [display property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/display/):

*Icon <span class=”display-none display-md-block”>Counter*

**And as to your comments:**

1. says to expand/collapse the nav bar as needed. If that is removed is there a way to force the navbar always up (I removed it and it was then always hamburger)?

*It’s the navbar-expand class that controls at what width the navbar is expanded.*

2. The whole  part in there is the hamburger button tied to the appropriate pieces of the navbar content.

*The navbar-toggler button uses the data-bs-target value to connect it to the navbar-collapse div.*

3. Is the <lt;button> shown/hidden based on class=“navbar-toggler” and the data-bs- and aria- settings?

*The navbar-toggler button is hidden by the navbar-collapse-md div. The data-bs-target tells Bootstrap which menu to show/hide. The aria settings are set by Bootstrap.*

4. Is the navbar items shown/hidden by <div class=“collapse navbar-collapse”>?

*Yes*

5. How does the navbar items know if they should display horizontally or vertically?

*The navbar item direction is set by the navbar-nav class flex direction. The direction is initially set to column, and then it’s switch to row through the navbar-expand-md class.*

6. The various mb-2, mb-4, mb-md-0 is all to adjust margins. Is this standard practice? Or are there bootstrap theme settings one should use so that everything stays consistent. And that a theme change adjusts everything?

*Bootstrap provides a set of standard [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) (e.g. ms-md-3)*

7. The display/hide of the menu is controlled by the